# sql modify primary key which is a fk in other tables

Tags: sql

I have a String primary key in a table, and i want to modify it as int auto increment, 
the problem is this primary key is also a foreign key in another table and is concatenate to its primary key, and both of them are foreign keys in another table. Does anyone knows the right way and order to perform this modification, for the foreign keys retrieve the right values when auto incrementing the primary key? thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to do this with a number of steps and it matters if the FK constraint are enforced by the RDBMS or not. In general you need to add temporary columns and play a bit of a shell game before removing / renaming columns to leave it correct. If you show a specific schema with the change you want to make, you probably get a pretty specific sequence suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this question depends on your database engine.

If you are using oracle, you would like to modify your constraint to be "deferred" - that would make changes within a transaction to violate the constraint, which will be validated on commit (it will not allow committing an FK that does not have a PK, but it will allow you to have a transaction that you can update both, without any issue).

Some databases have "on update cascade" for constraints, which allow cascading the update on the PK to the FK.